# How to convert List<Claim> to Dictionary<string,object>?

Tags: c#, list, dictionary

I'm getting my claims to put on jwt token

Get Valid Claims and Generate Jwt Token

```
var claims = await GetValidClaims(users);
Token = GenerateJwtToken(users, claims);
```

GenerateJwtToken Method

```
private string GenerateJwtToken(ApplicationUser user, List<Claim> claims)
{
    var dicClaim = new Dictionary<string,object>();
    ...
    var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
    {
        Claims = dicClaim,   // <<<<<<<<<< this Claims is Dictionary<string,object>
        ...
    }
}
```

GetValidClaims Method

```
private async Task<List<Claim>> GetValidClaims(ApplicationUser user)
{
    IdentityOptions _options = new IdentityOptions();
    var claims = new List<Claim>
    {
        new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, user.UserName),
        new Claim(_options.ClaimsIdentity.UserIdClaimType, user.Id.ToString()),
        new Claim(_options.ClaimsIdentity.UserNameClaimType, user.UserName)
    };
    var userClaims = await _userManager.GetClaimsAsync(user);
    var userRoles = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(user);
    claims.AddRange(userClaims);
    foreach (var userRole in userRoles)
    {
        claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, userRole));
        var role = await _roleManager.FindByNameAsync(userRole);
        if (role != null)
        {
            var roleClaims = await _roleManager.GetClaimsAsync(role);
            foreach (Claim roleClaim in roleClaims)
            {
                claims.Add(roleClaim);
            }
        }
    }
    return claims;
}
```

At this line: `Claims = dicClaim,   // <<<<<<<<<< this Claims is Dictionary<string,object>`

But I don't know how to convert List to Dictionary

I already tried something like this:

`claims.ToDictionary(x=>x,x=>x.Value)`

`claims.ToDictionary(x=>x.Value,x=>x)`

Lib `SecurityTokenDescriptor`
[image]

Comment: note that claims can be repeated. so it might not be unique key for the dictionary

Comment: I have no idea how to do this :/

Comment: What lib are you using for the `SecurityTokenDescriptor` object? The [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.identitymodel.tokens.securitytokendescriptor?view=netframework-4.5) doesn't mention a `Caims` property since .net framework 4.5... I couldn't figure out what is your intention with this code

Comment: @DiegoRafaelSouza Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens

Comment: Why not just loop throught the claims, adding an entry to your dictionary for each claim?

Comment: @JSON how can I do this? I don't know how to work with Dictionary... Sorry I'm new with this Collection... I tried with: `dicClaim.Add(item.Value,item);` is this correct?

Comment: You know how to do a foreach loop right?  Just create a dictionary like so, var myDictionary = new Dictionary()  Then loop through the claims and call myDictionary.Add(claim.ClaimType, claim.ClaimValue).  As stated earlier, claims can be repeated, meaning you can have an infinate number of claims with the same claim type, so a dictionary is probably not your best options.  What do you need this for?

Comment: sorry for the dictionary you need to define the types parameters var myDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>().  Honestly the anwer below works fine.  Just change the .GroupBy(claim => claim.Value) to .GroupBy(claim => claim.Type)

Comment: Thanks so much @JSON. Worked with foreach and I want to learn how do with anwer below too

Answer (score 6):

In order to create a *dictionary* we have to define a *unique* `Key` for it. Assuming that

1. We want our key to *be* say, `Type` or at least *start* from `Type`
2. Claims can be *repeated*

we can solve it like this:

1. `Group` all claims by `Type` (desired key)
2. If there's only `1` claim in a group, use `Value` as `Key`
3. If not, let's generate `Type_1`, `Type_2`, ..., `Type_N` `Key`s

Code

```
var dicClaim = claims
  .GroupBy(claim => claim.Type) // Desired Key
  .SelectMany(group => group
     .Select((item, index) => group.Count() <= 1
        ? Tuple.Create(group.Key, item) // One claim in group
        : Tuple.Create($"{group.Key}_{index + 1}", item) // Many claims
      )) 
  .ToDictionary(tuple => tuple.Item1, tuple => tuple.Item2);
```

If in case of *repeated* claims you want to get, say, the `Last` one only, you can do it with the code:

```
 var dicClaim = claims
   .GroupBy(claim => claim.Type) // Desired Key
   .ToDictionary(group => group.Key, group => group.Last());
```

Comment: At this lines, `group.value` doesn't contain a definition for value

Comment: If I remove `.Value` it works, but I got another error: Cannot implicitly convert type '...Dictionary<string,System.Linq.IGrouping<string, System.Security.Claims.Claim>>' to '...IDictionary<string, object>'

Comment: @LeoHenrique: I'm sorry for my typo, it should be `item`

Comment: This should be .GroupBy(claim => claim.Type).,  other wise this is correct